# How to explain a bivariate function is concave or convex in its arg.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to explain "intuitively" to a student what it means to be a bivariate real-valued function is concave or convex in its argument.

Of course, the most fundamental way to go about this is always return to definitions.

But, it doesn't always bring clarity nor intuition.

This was also the case when we went over saying f is non-decreasing in its argument or is non-increasing in its argument. The student knows the definition written in the text, but when he or she is asked to spit back in words what does it mean for a function to be non-decreasing or non-increasing in one of its argument, often there was some trouble.

Say $f(x,y)$ is a bivariate real valued function defined on positive orth. How would you go about explaining what it means, say $f$ is :

1. Non-decreasing in y
2. Non-increasing in y
3. Monotone in y
4. Concave in y
5. Convex in y

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to develop intuition, I'd say the definitions are not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: draw pictures.

I assume the student already understands what convexity means for functions of one variable.

So, to explain a function of two variables, you need to draw a graph, and then "slice" this graph using planes of the form $x=\text{constant}$ or $y=\text{constant}$. The slicing process gives you two families of planar curves, which the student already understands (I assume).

If you're not good at drawing freehand, use Mathematica, or a 3D CAD system, or similar.

[image]

Even better than pictures are 3D models, which are fairly easy to produce with a 3D printer, these days. You can slice these, too, if you have a good saw  :-).

Answer (score 1):

A function is convex (resp. concave) if it [lies above (resp. below) its tangent lines](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_Line_to_Convex_Graph).

I don't think nonincreasing or nondecreasing can be made any more intuitive (monotone is either nonincreasing or nondecreasing). Just draw a picture.